# How to reduce the size of the image from camera before saving it in a folder in android?like(3mb to ~300kb))

Tags: android, imageview

I am facing two issues.

- Issue 1.Below is my code where I open my camera,take a picture and save it in folder after some delay,I set that image to the particular image view(because it takes some time to save the image in a correct format into folder).

`Solution needed:` Want to set the image immediately after capturing without delay.

- Issue 2.I just want to compress the size of the image from 3mb to ~300kb. i searched but I didn't get the solution which suits to my code.

`Solution needed:` compressed image is very easy and less time consuming to upload the image to the server.

```
File imagesFolder = new File(image_path);
imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
final String image_name=getRandomStringForImage()+".png";
final File image = new File(imagesFolder, ""+image_name);

final String strFile=image.toString();
final Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
bt_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
bt_image.requestFocusFromTouch();

Intent intent=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
startActivity(intent);
ll_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
bt_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
formattedDate_question1 = df.format(c.getTime());

SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
formattedDate_user1 = df2.format(c.getTime());
Constants.endDateAndTime = df2.format(c.getTime());
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                iv_photo.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.body_bg_color));
                iv_photo.setImageURI(uriSavedImage); 

                Log.d("image", "image="+image+" name="+image_name+" str="+strFile);

            }
        });
        ImageFunctionality(Constants.survey_id, question_id, image_name);

    }
}, 15000);

}
});
```

Comment: Pls visit this link http://xmodulo.com/how-to-resize-image-captured-by-camera-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are using camera and picture is taken, you can perform the task in the method below to reduce the quality(*60 is used for now*) of the image and type like JPEG or PNG `(PNG takes more space than JPEG`).

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    preview_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Image1.jpg"));
        outStream.write(byteArray);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have  no idea how I am going this,the image capturing is not a single thing in activity it is a method,where I cannot go with global access,every think should be final.

Comment: `why can't you make them global?`

Comment: image capturing from camera is a method where i am dynamically adding it to my activity from the response i am getting from the back end.so the user can also add one or more image capturing(duplication may occur).in that case when i click an capture the image from the first button ,it will set the image to the second imageview.

Comment: How you are getting images from the camera? Post your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to reduce the size

Pass an integer value like 200 and so on

```
 public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float)width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```